# Prove Regarding Sigmoid Function and Softmax Function

Tags: probability, machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

In Machine Learning, `sigmoid` function is used to maximize the likelihood. [Right?]

> $$a(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\quad\{Sigmoid\;Function\}$$

which will give me the probability of success, now it's used when you only have *two classes to classify* which is equivalent to the `SoftMax` function

Before defining the `SoftMax` function, let's just say that there is some linear function that gives every a class a score based on some inputs, lets call it $L$

$$p(class[i]) = \frac{e^{L(i)}}{e^{L(1)}+e^{L(2)}+e^{L(3)}+.....+e^{L(n)}}$$

Now I'm struggling to prove that they're the same

> `SoftMax` Function : If Linear function scores are $Z_1,Z_2,...,Z_n$, then $$p(class[i]) = \frac{e^{Z_i}}{e^{Z_1}+e^{Z_2}+.....+e^{Z_n}}$$

Comment: I am not 100% sure I understand your question, but does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3496822/546005) answer your question?  If so, this is a duplicate.

Comment: yes, but I didn't get it though

Comment: You didn't get which part?  My answer in that other MSE post shows the equivalence. Specifically, when $n=2$ the sigmoid function calculates one value of the softmax function (which always calculates $n$ values).